# HTTP Post Request only when reloading the web page

Tags: python, angular, http, flask, post

**Hello everyone,**

I have a simple app coded with Angular9 where the user is supposed to pick two items in two separate dropdown list (selectedOption and selectedOption2) and then choose an option in a radio button list(= selctedOption3). I'd like to gather the results of the radio button form and send it to my Flask BackEnd.

Only problem is, I have a bit of a problem trying to manage the post method, my Get method works perfectly (it gathers a .json document)

Here is my Html code :

```
<form class='form' method='POST'>
<mat-radio-group class="radio" [(ngModel)]='selectedOption3' name='test'>
  <mat-radio-button class="button" *ngFor="let data3 of getThirdkeys(Data[selectedOption][selectedOption2])"
    [value]='data3' name='test2'>
    <div class="data3">{{data3}} </div>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

In my Angular main component I have :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

selectedOption = "";

selectedOption2 = "";

selectedOption3 = "";

Data : JSON;

private DRC_json = 'http://127.0.0.1:5100/drc_database.json';

private Images_DRC = 'http://127.0.0.1:5100/ReceiveImage';
constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit () {

  this.http.get<JSON>(this.DRC_json).subscribe((data: JSON)=>{console.log(data); this.Data = data;});

  this.http.post<any>(this.Images_DRC,this.selectedOption3).subscribe();

}
```

And finally my Flask code is :

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, request, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS
import os

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/GuideDRC/src')
CORS(app)

@app.route("/ReceiveImage", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Get_Image_DRC():
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Name_Image = request.data.decode('UTF-8')
        print(Name_Image)
        return '{}'.format(Name_Image)

app.run(debug=True, port=5100)
```

In the NetWork monitor of Google Chrome I can clearly see that my Post request is initialized, but since "SelectedOption3" is first null, it returns nothing, but then when I chose an option from my radio buttons nothing happens and the value of my post request is not updated ! Is there something that I'm missing ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not listen to radio button change and trigger your http call

```
<mat-radio-group class="radio" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]='selectedOption3' name='test'>
 <mat-radio-button class="button"  *ngFor="let data3 of getThirdkeys(Data[selectedOption][selectedOption2])"
[value]='data3' name='test2'>
<div class="data3">{{data3}} </div>
 </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

and in your ts file

```
onChange(event) {
  this.http.post<any>(this.Images_DRC,this.selectedOption3).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly ! So simple I can't believe I didn't think of it, thank you very much !